# Where can I find an app reading french slowly ?

Tags: prononciation

I am looking for a free application, preferably online, that will read the french text for me as audio. I tried google translate, but that "speaks" just too fast for me to learn pronunciation that way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for general references and research.  Please see https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/1893 for some suggestions, and stick around for when you have a specific question about the French language.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: On iPhone there is a parameter in accessibility to slow down or accelerate the voice when text is spoken